# R, change a character string in dataframe to binary values

Tags: r

My dataframe has a column called "LandType" of characters, either "Rural" or "Urban" for a bunch of samples. All I want to do is convert them to 1's and 0's, where "Rural" is 1, and "Urban" is 0.

I thought it would as simple as:

```
data$LandType[data$LandType == "Rural"] <- 1
data$LandType[data$LandType == "Urban"] <- 0
```

But after running this with no errors and then checking my data df, the crazy thing is that ONLY "Rural" has changed to 1's but Urban still remains as a string. I tried with different numbers but same thing happened, only Rural would change to the value I assigned.

Comment: Maybe `Urban` is written different in `data$Landtype` ? Check it e.g. with `table(data$Landtype)` or `unique(data$Landtype)`.

Comment: Okay I checked and it comes up as ```"Rural"``` and ```"Urban"```, and there are 72 "Rural" and 93 "Urban" samples.

Comment: `is.factor(data$Landtype)` gives `FALSE` ?

Comment: Yes it does because that column is a string of characters. I'll try converting it but not sure why then Rural would change to a value but Urban would not...

Comment: I don't understand. When checking the structure it shows as character even after just running ```as.factor(data$LandType)``` for the column. But, still only Rural will update the value but Urban will not....I have no clue what is causing this. ```is.factor``` still gives ```FALSE``` as well.

Comment: Once you use `LandType` the other time `Landtype`.

Comment: Fixed, that was my own typo writing it here. I always tab my variables to avoid typos like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `ifelse`

```
#your data
data = data.frame(Landtype = c("Rural", "Urban", "Rural", "Urban"))
#ifelse condition 
data$Landtype = ifelse(data$Landtype == "Rural", 1,0)
```

Comment: This worked! It is still incredibly odd to me that Urban would not change. I guess this was a nice workaround an odd situation like this. I also tried with using "Urban" in the ```ifelse``` statement and that seemed to work. Running it individually as I wrote above does not work.

Comment: This also avoids the problem of the data type on your 1's and 0's being changed to character as it did in the original.  Data.frames can only have a single type per column, so when you only replace half the values, it's forced to change the 1 to "1".

Answer (score 2):

A tidyverse option using `recode()`

```
library(dplyr)

mutate(data, Landtype = recode(Landtype, Rural = 1, Urban = 0))

# # A tibble: 4 x 1
# Landtype
# <dbl>
# 1        1
# 2        0
# 3        1
# 4        0
```

Data

```
data <- tibble(Landtype = c("Rural", "Urban", "Rural", "Urban"))
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case your way works:

```
set.seed(42)
data <- data.frame(LandType = sample(c(rep("Rural", 72), rep("Urban", 93))))

data$LandType[data$LandType == "Rural"] <- 1
data$LandType[data$LandType == "Urban"] <- 0

table(data$LandType)
# 0  1 
#93 72
```

To get *binary values* I would recommend to use the type `logical` (TRUE or FALSE).

```
data$LandType <- data$LandType == "Rural"
```

In case `0` and `1` is needed just add a `+`

```
data$LandType <- +(data$LandType == "Rural")
```

Comment: I know - there must be some weird error on my end that is not showing up in R as any warning/error. I checked the raw csv file as well and nothing seems out of place. Maybe a hidden character somewhere? That is my only conclusion.

Comment: Maybe `dput` your `data` to see where it comes from.

Answer (score 0):

We could use `as.integer`

```
data$Landtype <- as.integer(data$Landtype == "Rural")
```

#### data

```
data = data.frame(Landtype = c("Rural", "Urban", "Rural", "Urban"))
```